# Integration Between Oracle Apex 5.1 And Oracle Fusion

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-fusion-middleware

Hello I'm really new on using Oracle Apex.
I want to get some data report from Oracle Fusion Instance and put the data into Oracle Apex Table. Since the Apex 5.1 doesn't have  'REST Data Sources' menu  under 'Shared Component'is there any way to connect between those two instance. Thanks before

A documentation how to connect between Oracle apex and Oracle Fusion without using 'REST Data Sources' Menu

Comment: Apex 5.1 is really old. It would be best if you could **upgrade**.

Comment: ahh i'm sorry mate, its for my work project .... i wish my client not a cheapskate  to use old apps.

Comment: Apex applications developed in old(er) Apex version still work in newer Apex versions. For example, one of my applications was developed in Apex 3.2 and works OK in Apex 20.2. Try to suggest your client to - at least - consider upgrading.

Comment: ah i see, but is it possible to get data from oracle fusion into apex? despite it's old version
if can can u give some tips?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Oracle Fusion; I was just hoping that - if you could upgrade Apex - you'd be able to use functionalities that lower versions don't have. On the other hand, perhaps you could create a **database link** between your Apex application and schema that contains the *Fusion* data. Doing so, you'd be able to create reports or whatever you want in Apex.

Comment: Or you could install apex in the same database as the fusion data. Then you can just access the tables directly or create synonyms

Comment: But as @Littlefoot said, tell your client to upgrade APEX. APEX is free and version 5.1 no longer supported since dec 2021. You'll have a hard time finding help if you run into issues.

Comment: Two things:

- As Littlefoot mentioned above, APEX 5.1 is pretty old. It's also _out of support_ since December 2021. So this APEX instance _should definitively_ be upgraded to a newer and supported version.

- When you don't have REST Data Sources, the only way of integrating is to implement custom PL/SQL code, using the APEX_WEB_SERVICE package. Your code can perform the HTTP request to the REST API, then parse and process the JSON.

Comment: Ahh thank you for you guys suggestion is really" help. But thx to @Carsten it just got me an idea by using custom pl/sql code. thank you